# How to style a context menu background to OS default styling instead of transparent

Tags: firefox-addon, contextmenu, xul

In my Firefox extension I have a tree that has a context menu assigned. The context menu displays and is functional, but the background is transparent. The row data of the tree shows through the context menu. How can I set it to the default OS context menu style?

My XUL `treechildren` tag with the menu assigned

```
<treechildren id="my_children" contextmenu="my_context">

</treechildren>
```

The XUL context menu

```
<popup id="my_context">
   <menuitem label="Start" oncommand="myApp.start()"/>
</popup>
```

I have noticed that the Tamper Data extension has this exact same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is really simple. From the [documentation for the `<xul:popup>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/popup):

> The popup element is equivalent to the [menupopup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menupopup) element which should be used instead.

Just replace `<popup>` by `<menupopup>`. The `<popup>` tag has been deprecated and unstyled for a while already, since Firefox 4 I think. You probably have it from a very outdated code example.